# Search Form Multi Input

Tags: php, mysql

I have a search form with 2 select fields and one input, total 3 options, so i created some if statements, depending of each fields are set it haves is own query, but its not working well, is all buggy, the results doesn't get right, it gets mixed up with the statements queries, it's not getting right.

Here is my code for the search form result:

```
$keywords = $_GET["Keywords"]; 
             $location = $_GET['Location']; 
             $jobtype = $_GET["Category"];


              if (isset($location) && empty($jobtype) && empty($keywords)){

              $sql_jobs = "SELECT * FROM jobs 
                            WHERE  
                            active = '1' AND 
                            country = '$location' 
                            ORDER BY id_job DESC";

                }elseif(isset($location) && isset($jobtype) && empty($keywords)){
                     $sql_jobs = "SELECT * FROM jobs 
                            WHERE  
                            active = '1' AND 
                            country = '$location' AND
                            jobType_en = '$jobtype'
                            ORDER BY id_job DESC";

                }elseif(isset($location) && isset($jobtype) && isset($keywords)){
                     $sql_jobs = "SELECT * FROM jobs 
                            WHERE  
                            active = '1' AND 
                            country = '$location' AND
                            jobType_en = '$jobtype' AND
                            title_en LIKE '%$keywords%'
                            ORDER BY id_job DESC";

                }elseif(empty($location) && isset($jobtype) && empty($keywords)){
                     $sql_jobs = "SELECT * FROM jobs 
                            WHERE  
                            active = '1' AND 
                            jobType_en = '$jobtype'
                            ORDER BY id_job DESC";

                }elseif(empty($location) && isset($jobtype) && isset($keywords)){
                     $sql_jobs = "SELECT * FROM jobs 
                            WHERE  
                            active = '1' AND 
                            jobType_en = '$jobtype' AND
                            title_en LIKE '%$keywords%'
                            ORDER BY id_job DESC";
                }elseif(empty($location) && isset($jobtype) && isset($keywords)){
                     $sql_jobs = "SELECT * FROM jobs 
                            WHERE  
                            active = '1' AND 
                            jobType_en = '$jobtype' AND
                            title_en LIKE '%$keywords%'
                            ORDER BY id_job DESC";
                }
                else{
                     $sql_jobs = "SELECT * FROM jobs 
                            WHERE  
                            active = '1' 
                            ORDER BY id_job DESC";
                }

                $consultaJob = mysql_query($sql_jobs);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try strlen() rather than isset or empty

otherwise you have to use both `isset()` and `empty()`

`empty()` does not generate a warning if the variable does not exist.

strlen() will return zero on NULL and ''.

You can set minimum lengths by changing the zero to a higher value.

```
elseif(strlen($location) > 0 && strlen($jobtype) > 0  && strlen($keywords) > 0 ){
```

If the submitted values are text inputs then you may need the trim also:

```
elseif(strlen(trim($location)) > 0 && strlen(trim($jobtype)) > 0  && strlen(trim($keywords)) > 0 ){
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to simplify the code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM jobs 
                            WHERE  
                            active = '1' AND 
                            country = '$location' ";
$order = "ORDER BY id_job DESC";
$where = "";

if( isset( $jobtype ) { $where .= " AND jobType_en = '$jobtype'"; }
if( isset($keywords) { $where .= " AND title_en LIKE '%$keywords%'" };

$sqlx = $sql . $where . $order;
```

You are obviously processing $jobtype and $keywords earlier on. In this processing you should be setting some default values to make later processing easier.

```
$jobtitle = (isset( $_GET['jobtitle'] ) ) ? $_GET['jobtitle'] : "";
$keywords= (isset( $_GET['keywords'] ) ) ? $_GET['keywords'] : "";
```

This way you can use:

```
if( $jobtitle != '') { .... }
```

Comment: isset does not check if value is empty.